# Trying to validate PS3 input based on menu output for user validation

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

If i wanted to validate a null return from a user keyboard input if the user hasn't selected an option to reprint the menu how could this be achieved? and if a invalid choice is made to clear the screen / reprint the menu but insure the error message is still visible? maybe capture a return code as part of the exit and based on that provide an error?

The file ALIAS_FILE.config consists of these values:

```
ALIAS1 CLUSTER1
ALIAS2 CLUSTER2
ALIAS3 CLUSTER3
QUIT
```

Script:

```
mapfile -t arr < "/var/ALIAS_FILE.config"

            select alias_select in "${arr[@]}"
            do
            if [[ -z "$alias_select" ]]
            then
                echo
                echo "Invalid Choice"
                echo

            elif [[ $alias_select == "QUIT" ]]
            then
                break
            else
                echo
                echo "You selected: $alias_select"
                echo

                ALIAS=$(echo "${alias_select}" | awk '{print $1}')
                CLUSTER=$(echo "${alias_select}" | awk '{print $2}')

                echo "$ALIAS"
                echo "$CLUSTER"
            fi
            done
```

Comment: @anubhava your thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you have your file (`/var/ALIAS_FILE.config`), you should be able to show the menu anytime, you also have access to the values in arr through `mapfile` here is a quick attempt, with some advices:

- use `echo -e` or event better (*and recommended*) `printf`
- clear screen, you can use VT100 escape code `printf "\033c"`
- use [bash string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)

**updated script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

mapfile -t arr< "/var/ALIAS_FILE.config"

print_menu(){
    for (( i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i++ ));
    do
      echo $i")" ${arr[$i]}
    done
}

printf "\033c"

select alias_select in "${arr[@]}"
do
printf "\033c"
if [[ -z "$alias_select" ]]
then
    echo -e "\nInvalid Choice\n"
    print_menu
elif [[ $alias_select == "QUIT" ]]
then
    break
else
    echo -e "\nYou selected: $alias_select\n"
    echo -e "${alias_select// *}\n${alias_select##* }"
fi
done
```

Comment: This worked accordingly however wondering is it possible to also recreate the menu input again if the PS3 input from the user is just a return / null (enter) answer?